# Paperclip error [paperclip] Content Type Spoof on staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I managed to set up Paperclip on my company project and everything works fine on my local machine, the files are both saved locally and on my S3 bucket, but when i make the deploy to our staging environt the following error show in the log:

> Command :: file -b --mime
>   '/tmp/82ec0de52ea6371366640c52ac59bc3120170412-25375-1gm001x.pdf' I,
>   [2017-04-12T20:45:53.506732 #25375]  INFO -- : [paperclip] Content
>   Type Spoof: Filename test.pdf  (application/pdf from Headers,
>   ["application/pdf"] from Extension), content type discovered from file
>   command: . See documentation to allow this combination.

The error of spoofed media type shows up on the screen. And I cannot find anything on the internet about this specific situation.

Comment: This suggests a problem with the `file` utility not running thus returning no content type.  Does the command `file -b --mime '/tmp/82ec0de52ea6371366640c52ac59bc3120170412-25375-1gm001x.pdf` work on this machine?

Answer (score 1):

This problem arises because for some reason `/usr/bin` is not in the `$PATH` that is used by Paperclip when running through Passenger.  To resolve, add the following to `config/environments/production.rb` (or similar):

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
```